# Firebase data retrieval without one of the child node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Picture of my database]

Hi guys. I got stuck with a problem with firebase database. I wanted to get last two `processdata` object based on timestamp. I don’t want it to be returned within parent object of `processdata`, because the requirement is `rawdata` object which is another child of parent object should not be send to the application side. So getting parent object also get `rawdata` as it is also child. How can I avoid it? Following code return `processdata` within parent object as I said

```
var firebaseHeadingRef6 = firebase.database().ref('pond2/temperature');

firebaseHeadingRef6.orderByChild("{key}/processdata/timestamp").limitToLast(2).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  When you load any data from firebase, all its child data comes along for the ride. Emphasis mine:

> **when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes**. In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, **it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible**. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Store your `rawdata` separately from the data that should be sent to the client.